# How to generate UI using EDMX file

Tags: javascript, html, entity-framework, odata, edmx

1. What is an EDMX file and what is it used to do?
2. Could I create a UI screen from EDMX file?
3. If yes, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is the conceptual model for Microsoft's Entity Framework.
2. It is used as a data layer, you could build a ui that is rendered from the model produced via the Entity Framework.
3. Yes, you could use Microsoft's MVC and the Entity framework to do this however the scope of this would be very wide. You would be better of looking for a tutorial on this, there are many on http://asp.net/

Comment: Could I consume this file in javascript (without using any of microsoft's tool) and render a UI? I mean technically I know I could parse the XML and read and render it - but my question is, is this how is it supposed to be used?  I am asking this because I have received this file from someone and been asked it use it for UI - now in our project we use HTML5 and javascript (with a lean Java layer).

Comment: I've never seen a UI generated in this way before. It is purely for a conceptual model of your database which I'm guessing you would not want to expose on a website/web application. It is mainly used as a designer tool for the database, you could always just take a screen dump and render the image. Seems like a lot of work parsing the microsoft specific xml.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yeah this is what I was wondering too. Thanks for confirming it.